# Can I use an anchor element with download attribute to download a rar in Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I created a landing page for a game and I want to add a button that downloads a `.rar` of the game. So I tried putting a `.rar` file in `src/assets` folder and then attempted to download it using this:

```
<a class="download" href="../assets/file.rar" download>Play Now</a>
```

But when I click on the `<a>` element, the download says `Failed - No File`.

I'm suspecting a path mistake, my project folder structure is like this:

```
root -> src -> assets -> file.rar
```

And the component which houses my `<a>` element is in this folder:

```
root -> src -> components -> Header.vue
```

Hence why I got 1 folder up and then in assets. That being said, the path doesn't seem to be right.

Also when I `npm run build` the project for production, the `.rar` doesn't go in the dist folder. It's as if it is being skipped.

Comment: I know it's not answering you question, but I think keeping `.rar` file in your `dist` is not a good approach. Maybe just move the file to your public server and then just replace project path with path that leads to this file on your server?

Comment: Yes, assets are usually related to the site itself, not user content.

Comment: i think you should use `require()` for example `require('../assets/file.rar')`